# XNA - File Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, filenotfoundexception

Can't find the answer anywhere, hoping you guys can help, thanks in advanced.
        These were loaded in the beginning of the file-

```
    SpriteBatch mBatch;
    Texture2D mTheQuantumBros2;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        mBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        //Create the Content Manager object to load images
        ContentManager aLoader = new ContentManager(this.Services);
        //Use the Content Manager to load the Cat Creature image into the Texture2D object
        mTheQuantumBros2 = aLoader.Load<Texture2D>("TheQuantumBros2") as Texture2D;
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }
```

Error is saying the file is not found. File is TheQuantumBros2.png and I tried loading under the original game area and the content area. Neither is working and I put them in the directory and loaded them into the game on Visual Studio also. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A few things could be happening...

Firstly, I see that you are are trying to make a new ContentManager. In my experience it is a lot easier to use the manager that is "built-in". Usually, it is either called 'contentManager', or 'Content' and is created when the class 'game1.cs' is generated. In general, it is best to simply use one content manager.

This is the correct content manager to use. In the constructor for "Game1.cs" it should say Content.RootDirectory = "Content". This tells the manager where the file is located. In your code, that is what you are missing. It simply does not know where to look for the file.

So add this to your code:

```
SpriteBatch mBatch;
Texture2D mTheQuantumBros2;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
    mBatch = new SpriteBatch(this.graphics.GraphicsDevice);
    //Create the Content Manager object to load images
    ContentManager aLoader = new ContentManager(this.Services);


    //ADD THIS
    aLoader.RootDirectory = "Content";


    //Use the Content Manager to load the Cat Creature image into the Texture2D object
    mTheQuantumBros2 = aLoader.Load<Texture2D>("TheQuantumBros2") as Texture2D;
    // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}
```

Comment: I have another question I think you can answer Colton, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553842/xna-drawing-strings-on-menus