# XNA - Drawing Strings on Menus

Tags: c#, menu, xna

Two questions on Drawing a list of Strings on XNA in menus. First is how do you left align the text instead of center align it? Second is how do you show a say a line before whichever one is selected?
Here is the code I have for it so far;

```
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Color color;
        int linePadding = 3;

        if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds <= 3)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mTheQuantumBros2, new Rectangle(300, 150, mTheQuantumBros2.Width, mTheQuantumBros2.Height), Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                color = (i == selected) ? Color.Gold : Color.LawnGreen;
                spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((screenWidth / 2) - (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2), (screenHeight / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm.. honestly I think center aligning would look better, but in your code all you would need to do is change draw string to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
{
     color = (i == selected) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Gold;
     spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((screenWidth / 2) /*- (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2)*/, (screenHeight / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
}
```

You can see what I commented out. By taking that out, you are no longer moving the string to the left by half of its width.

As for the second part, all you need to do is check if the value is selected, as you are already doing to determine the menu item color. If it is selected, simply add "|" to the front and end of the string:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
{
     color = (i == selected) ? Color.LawnGreen : Color.Gold;
     if(i != selected)
     {
         spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2((screenWidth / 2) /*- (spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X / 2)*/, (screenHeight / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
     }
     else
     {
         spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont,"|" + buttonList[i] + "|", new Vector2((screenWidth / 2) - (int)spriteFont.MeasureString("|").X, (screenHeight / 2) - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i)), color);
     }
}
```

Now, since you are adding the "|" to the beginning of the string, that will effect the position. By subtracting the measured width of "|", the string is then recentered.

Comment: Firstly, I want it left aligned because how I want to move it, since you're being so helpful, when I fully finish the menu I will show you and ask your opinion on it. Secondly, how would you make the | in front of the screen be a specified color? And third, in the second spritebatch.DrawString, is that left aligned or did you make that center align?

Comment: Try it and see :p. If you also want to change the color, you'll have to draw it separately in a different string. You would simply have to call drawstring() twice, once for each "|", placing them at the same x value minus the measured width of the string ('|') for the first string, and add the width of the button string to the x coord for the second string.

Comment: Also, by left aligning the text, it is impossible to make all of them also align with the center of the screen. They will be mathematically off no matter what unfortunately. You can see this if you just try to write these out on a piece of paper. Only one string could be aligned to the center (and all strings of the same length would also be aligned) but the others would have to be aligned with the front of another string.

Comment: How do you find the x and y co-ords of the selected string? Also I'm not putting them in the center, that was just while I make the buttons

Comment: Using the same math that was used to place them. Simply store the x and y variables of the selected value when they are calculated.

Comment: I tried using "spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).Y" for the Y but it is way higher than the button?

Comment: That is because you are not using that y coord at all. You should be calculating it the EXACT same way as where you are creating your `new Vector2()` inside of .DrawString().

Comment: Okay I got that, now how do you make a font bold? Also should we switch over to chat so this doesn't get too lengthy publicly?

Comment: Don't forget you also have google for those easy questions ^^.

Comment: Why use Google when I have you? Just kidding, okay I won't.

Comment: Here's a question google didn't answer; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556071/xna-how-to-exit-game-from-class-other-than-main