# XNA - How to Exit Game from class other than main?

Tags: c#, menu, xna, exit

How do you make it so the game can exit but not have the code in the main class, have it in a different class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a method:

```
//Inside of game1.cs
public void Quit()
{
    this.Exit()
}
```

I'm assuming you want to quit the game on a menu component, in which case you will need to pass the instance of game1 to the component, perhaps add it as a parameter in the menu components update method.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 game)
{
     if(key is pressed)
     {
          game.Quit();
     }
}
```

I'm not sure if there are any other ways... Perhaps finding a way to "force" the close button to press.

In order to send the instance of game1.cs:

```
//in game1.cs
//in your update method
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     //sends the current game instance to the other classes update method, where
     // quit might be called.
     otherClass.Update(gameTime, this);
     //where 'this' is the actual keyword 'this'. It should be left as 'this'
}
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game' does not contain a definition for 'Quit' and no extension method 'Quit' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think you are still trying to use it wrong. Make sure you are calling game, the instance, not Game, the class. Quit is a method I made up containing this.Exit(), and this.Exit() is what closes the page. Mind you, the update method showed above is in the non-game1 class, and a new parameter is being passed to the update method (Game game) which was not there before.

Comment: I figured it out, it is meant to be Game1 game not Game game, but when I debug it says this; Object reference not set to an instance of an object. and highlights game.Quit();

Comment: Thanks, I used game instead of this on what you put above, so it wasn't working but now it does.

Comment: Hmm.... that really should not have made a difference. By sending Game1, you can ONLY send Game1. You will not be able to send a Game2 later on. I ran the code with just Game game and it worked fine...

Comment: I have no clue, but it made a difference. Any clue how to fix this error "Field 'Warfare_1_PC.Game1.zMenuComponent' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null" in this code-                case "ZMenu":
                    zMenuComponent.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime);
                    break;

Comment: Uhm... I imagine you just never set zMenuComponent = new MenuComponent().. Or..."ZMenu" is not meant to be a string? I'm not sure with with just that context.

Comment: I fixed it, it was I forgot to add the zMenuComponent to LoadContent in Game1

Comment: Sorry but I need a bit more help please Colton; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576796/xna-how-to-change-orientation-of-drawing-a-list-of-strings

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a sort of singleton pattern, whereby in your main game class you define a static variable of the type of that class. When you construct or initialize that class, you then set that variable to `this`, allowing you to have an easily accessible reference to the instance of the class anywhere.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public static Game1 self;

    public Game1()
    {
        self = this;
        //... other setup stuff ...
    }

    //... other code ...
}
```

Then, when you want to call a method in this class from pretty much anywhere in code, you would simply do:

```
Game1.self.Exit(); //Replace Exit with any method
```

This works as there should only usually be a single `Game` class in existence. Naturally, if you were to somehow have multiple `Game` classes, this method won't work as well.

Comment: I love this solution :)

Answer (score 3):

In your main game class (`Game1` by default) use a global variable:

```
public static Boolean exitgame = false;
```

In the Game1 update routine:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{    
     SomeOtherClass.Update(gameTime);
     if (exitgame) this.Exit();
     base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the XNA engine to close immediately like this:

```
Game.Exit();
```

This will immediately exit the game. Note that I say `Game.Exit()` - Game should be your game instance. If you are coding within a class that implements `Game`, you can simply do the following:

`Exit()`

Comment: I get this error and I can't figure out how to fix it; "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Exit()'"

Comment: Game isn't actually static, I was wrong at first about that. Something in your project should extend Game, or you are creating a new Game. Wherever that is, just use myGame.Exit() (where myGame is the instance of Game).