# XNA - How to change orientation of Drawing a List of Strings

Tags: c#, list, xna, drawstring, spritebatch

How do you Draw a list of strings with a spritebatch so that it looks like this;

```
Item1 Item2
Item3 Item4
```

Instead of Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 or instead of:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
Item4
```

Comment: Just create a loop; you can use two if you want. There's a number of ways to do this. The easiest way to do is is every 2nd iteration, increment your line count. Then draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would make it a little easier to change later on:

```
int y = startPointY;
int x = startPointX;
int switchAt = items.Count/2; //<--- or where ever you might want to break up the strings
int max = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    spriteBatch.DrawString(font, items[i], new Vector2(x, y), Color);

    if(max < spriteFont.MeasureString(items[i]))
    {
        //this is to make sure the next column of strings are aligned
        max = spriteFont.MeasureString(items[i]);
    }

    y += someYSpace;

    if(i == switchAt)
    {
         x += max + someXSpace;//someXSpace not neccessary
         y = startPointY;         
    }         
}
```

Now, you can either guess the approximate position to center the strings.... or, you can find the lengths of the strings that will be side by side, measure the total amount of space that would be between them, and some other tricky stuff to figure out which strings should be placed where... In other words, getting them perfectly centered would be a pain and probably a lot more trouble than its worth, as far as I can tell.

Your refactored code:

```
        Color color;
        int linePadding = 3;
        int switchAt = buttonList.Count / 2 - 1;//minus one because the list starts at 0, and goes up to 3, so 1 is the switch point


        else
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mMenuPhoto, new Rectangle(800, 150, mMenuPhoto.Width, mMenuPhoto.Height), Color.White);  
            float X = 210;
            float Y = 600 - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding));
            float max = 0;
            float linesXSpace = 30;//to seperate this lines to make room for '|'

            for (int i = 0; i < buttonList.Count; i++)
            {
                color = (i == selected) ? Color.LightGray : Color.DarkSlateGray;
                if (max < spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X)
                {
                    max = spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).X;
                }

                if (i != selected)
                {
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2(X, Y), color);
                    Y += spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).Y;    
                    if (i == switchAt)
                    {
                        X += max + linesXSpace;
                        Y = 600 - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding));
                    }                       

                }
                else
                {     
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont, buttonList[i], new Vector2(X, Y), color);
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spriteFont2, "|", new Vector2(X - 20, Y), Color.DarkGreen);
                    Y += spriteFont.MeasureString(buttonList[i]).Y;   
                    if (i == switchAt)
                    {
                        X += max + linesXSpace;
                        Y = 600 - (spriteFont.LineSpacing * (buttonList.Count) / 2) + ((spriteFont.LineSpacing + linePadding) * i);
                    }                                             
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S. I like the way it looks so far ^^.

Comment: See why I wanted the left align? :P

Comment: You might want to allow them to press left and right to scroll left and right on the menu as well, just to make it a little more intuitive. But it works either way.

Comment: Colton can you think of a good name for a war game? I keep drawing blanks... It'd be nice if the name could be made a series if it's successful.

Comment: Heh... why not Quantum Brothers?

Comment: How is that a war game name :P?

Comment: Uh.. well you see... there will be quantum... enemies. Yes.

Comment: Maybe Quantum Warfare would work if it was like a Halo game xD but this isn't high tech quantum stuff, this is the low tech dumb stuff

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30029/discussion-between-thequantumbros-and-colton)